# Resetting only a part of a UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, swift, date, uidatepicker

I have a date picker where users can select their date of birth. I've set a maximum date so users who are born after 2000 can't use the app. Below is my code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        datePicker.maximumDate = Date.earliestValidDate
        datePicker.date = Date.initialDate
    }

    @IBAction func didSelectDate(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
        if sender.date > Date.earliestValidDate {
            print("Invalid date!")
            return
        }
        print(DateFormatter.localizedString(from: sender.date, dateStyle: .medium, timeStyle: .none))
    }

}

extension Date {
    public static var earliestValidDate: Date {
        let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        return calendar.date(byAdding: .year, value: -18, to: Date())!
    }

    public static var initialDate: Date {
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.year = 1995
        components.month = 1
        components.day = 1

        let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        return calendar.date(from: components)!
    }
}
```

My problem is a bit of a usability related. Say, a user select the day and the month and while selecting the year, they select an invalid year. Then the entire picker resets to the current date. This is explanable since I'm setting the max date 18 years ago from the current date.

[image]

I want to preserve the user selected day and the month only reset the year.

I tried to catch invalid dates within the `didSelectDate` method with the `if` case but it keeps falling through. My plan is to extract the day and the month from the `sender.date` if it's an invalid date, and then create a new date object with that day, month plus the max date's year as a new date object and set it as the current date. But not being able to determine invalid dates has me stumped.

[Sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ftgmuudqz5d9hss/DateReset.zip?dl=0)

Comment: What about setting no maximum/minimum date for the picker, but keep them "internal" in your code. Once the user chose a Date, if not valid, change only the year?

Comment: @Larme That's an option. Thanks. I have to run it by the client to see if he's ok with it. If there's no other way at all, I'll go this route.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways as I see to change only year.

As per @Larme explained well, without set minimum/maximum date; check & change maximum year when invalid date selected.

```
extension UIDatePicker {

    public func checkMaxYear() {
        let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        var component = calendar.dateComponents([.day,.month], from: self.date)
        component.year = calendar.dateComponents([.year], from: Date.earliestValidDate).year
        let newDate = calendar.date(from: component)!
        self.setDate(newDate, animated: true)
    }
}

//Call checkMaxYear() extension when invalid date

if sender.date > Date.earliestValidDate {
    print("Invalid date!")
    datePicker.checkMaxYear()
    return
}
```

Another way is set maximum date whenever user change day/month/year in datePicker

```
func changeMaximumDate() {

    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    var component = calendar.dateComponents([.day,.month], from: self.datePicker.date)
    component.year = calendar.dateComponents([.year], from: Date.earliestValidDate).year
    component.month = component.month
    component.day = component.day

    datePicker.maximumDate = calendar.date(from: component)!

}

@IBAction func didSelectDate(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {

    //Change maximum date
    changeMaximumDate()

    //...rest code
}
```